# wxPython: Placement of scrollbar in ScrolledPanel

Tags: python, wxpython

I was wondering if there is any way to control the location of the scrollbar from a scrolledpanel? More specifically: I use a horizontally scrolled panel and it would be nice if the scrollbar was on top of the panel (instead of bottom) and would only span 80% of the horizontal distance.

Is something like this possible?

Thanks...

Comment: Off the top of my head, no there isn't. However, have you tried implementing your own ScrolledPanel? Maybe take a look at the [wx.ScrollBar](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ScrollBar-class.html) class

Comment: Thanks, I was already thinking about that. Guess I will re-evaluate whether the visual bonus from this is worth the extra effort...